# I need a static domain like ngrok but static

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ssh, nlp-question-answering

I'm creating a reverse shell in c# and i don't want to put my IP on the reverse shell, even it is encrypted or something on wire shark the IP pops up (obs:i don't realy want to use it in the bad away I'm ethical just like to learn new stuff)
if someone can help me i would appreciate

sorry for bad English

Comment: An IP header has source and destination IP.  You cannot make a connection without the IP address.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

Comment: yep i know im searching for an away to hide it somehow like ngrok is good or it but it dreates a new domain everytime

Comment: ngrok create a tunnel through a firewall by using port forwarding.  The tunnel uses an existing IP connection to forward messages.  It cannot be used to create a connection like your reverse shell since a connection doesn't exist the supports port forwarding.

Comment: sorry but yes it can with tcp connection it can just create a ngrok tcp connection and in the # reverse shell on the tcp socket just put the link and the respective port and the connection pops ups on netcat.... im searching for something like ngrok but with a static domain      ps(imagine i have port 2005 on my ip then i open tcp ngrok on that port and it works fine like on netcat i use "nc -lvp 2005" and on the reverse shell i use the ngrok domain and port........ it works becouse ngrok transfer the info from their port to my 2005 port

Comment: You are creating a custom protocol that uses a tcp port.  It is similar to encrypting on one end of the tcp port and then decrypting on the other end.